# Auto-rotation in ios6 not working as expected

Tags: ios, iphone, ios6, autorotate

I have two views in my app; "Calculator" and the "Tape". I can click on the button inside calculator to get to the tape and vice versa. I set the rotation as per code below and it works fine most of the time.

However there are issues if I rotate either calculator view or tape view to landscape and then if I try to access other view, interface is all messed up like it doesn't recognize that device was already rotated. Any suggestions?

```
- (void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation) toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration 
{
    [self doLayoutForOrientation:toInterfaceOrientation]; 
}


- (void)doLayoutForOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)orientation { 
if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(orientation)) 
{
//set the frames here
}
else 
{
//set the frames here
} 
}
```

Comment: when you go to another view (say tape) from an already rotated view the device does not recognize the view has been changed.

Comment: so u need to check the current orientation of the device in the view will appear of the next view and adjust the view

Comment: Great, works like a dream.

Comment: am glad that i could help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

write these codes in the view will appear of each view.

```
 UIInterfaceOrientation orientation = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation];
if(orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight)
{
//adjust the view for landscape
}
else if(orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait || orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown)
{
//adjust the view for portrait.
}
```